# is reselling virtual "in game" items legal in the USA?

Tags: united-states, copyright, tax-law, business, cryptocurrency

If I were to buy virtual in game items through third party websites which is against the game's TOS with bitcoin then resell them for more money is that legal?

Comment: Edited title to avoid a crash blossom. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/crash_blossom

Answer (score 0):

US laws around "misuse of computer systems" can be so vague as to be hard to predict the legality out in the wild, but generally violating the TOS isn't illegal.  Zealous prosecutors have really gone after people for crazy things around computers (for example, using a misuse of computer systems law to prosecute people doing return scams at a store because returns use a computer).  Because of the way that prosecution works in the US, fighting the bogus use of such laws is difficult and risky - very few offenses actually go to trial.